How to record time between item created and status change in sharepoint?
I want to get the time between when an item is created in the sharepoint list to when i update a specific (status) column.
however, there are multiple different statuses, so the modified timestamp will keep changing whenever the status updates. i only want the time difference for the first change in status.
please help
i tried using power automate to detect when item is modified but it will keep changing.

A suggested approach is to create a new datetime column in your list. Then with Power Automate, only update this column on first modified/update.
For example in pseudo code:
When item is modified
* check status column <> default value and newDateTimeColumn is null
* if yes, update newDateTimeColumn


@helpmepls You can create a new column of type DateTime and a column named RunWorkflow of type true/false. inside the power automate only run the flow if the RunWorkflow flag is set to true, this will avoid your workflow to keep triggering. then inside the workflow update the custom column of type DateTime and set the flag to false, so the workflow will not get triggered again. and so on. try and let me know if you need further help.
Also when the workflow runs, reset the flag back to false.
